# Human Resources allocation/skills tool with utilization dashboards

Tags: resource-management, human-resources

I'm a Resource Manager of a 200+-employee software company working on multiple accounts/clients. I'm looking for a good solution that can help me with the following:

- Allocate resources to different project
- Generate resource utilization reports/dashboards
- Employee skills matrix dashboard
- (Optional) Generate employee experience profiles (much like a resume/CV)

Great, if Employees can update their skills. Woudn't mind online/offline/commercial/opensource solution. At most, 3 people from the resource planning team would use it.

Comment: What OS (or online?), what price? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question. And remove your comment about *any*; you can't ask for *any* here.

Comment: Who will use the software? Only you, or the entire HR team, or all employees? For instance, will the employees update their skills via a web interface, or will you do that yourself for them? Also, is gratis/open source a requirement?